# Javascript doesn't update value of input on first keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a script that will detect if one input field is greater than another whilst the user types.

So I have two input fields: length, and width. When the user types "1" into the length, and then "2" into the width, the submit button should be greyed out as the length is shorter than the width. If they then typed "12" into the length without modifying the width field, it should validate and make the submit button clickable.

My problem with my code is that the first entry into the field is not registered. For example, if I console.log the input field, the first keypress is registered as "NaN".

I have attached a jsfiddle of my work so far, you can see that if you enter a number into one of the fields, nothing updates in the HTML. However, if you then type another number, you see the value of the field 1 step earlier.

I hope this makes sense and hope somebody can help me with this

https://jsfiddle.net/smyckdb8/

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
        $('p.length span').html(parseInt($(".length-field").val()));
        $('p.width span').html(parseInt($(".width-field").val()));

        if (parseInt($(".length-field").val()) > parseInt($(".width-field").val())) {
            $('.result').html('L > W');
        };
        if (parseInt($(".length-field").val()) < parseInt($(".width-field").val())) {
            $('.result').html('W > L');
        };

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    Length
</p>
<input type="number" class="length-field">
<p>
    Width
</p>
<input type="number" class="width-field">
<p class="length">length is <span></span></p>
<p class="width">width is <span></span></p>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: Use defaultValue property to set the initial value of two fields to 0 instead of empty which results in NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use keyup event instead of keypress

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('input').on('keyup', function(e){
    $('p.length span').html(parseInt($(".length-field").val()));
  $('p.width span').html(parseInt($(".width-field").val()));


    if( parseInt($(".length-field").val()) > parseInt($(".width-field").val()) ){


        $('.result').html('L > W');
    };
    if( parseInt($(".length-field").val()) < parseInt($(".width-field").val()) ){


        $('.result').html('W > L');
    };

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Length
</p>
<input type="number" class="length-field">
<p>
Width
</p>    
<input type="number" class="width-field">
<p class="length">length is <span></span></p>
<p class="width">width is <span></span></p>
<p class="result">

</p>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. What is the reason for keyup rather than keypress?

Comment: Keypress checks the field when the key is pressed, before the value has been input to the field. Keyup makes it check the field when the key is released and since the field gets filled when the key is pressed it contains a value on keyup and not on keypress.

Comment: Keypress event happens before the input change. But Keyup happens after the change. So keypress shows the previous input on the next while keyup shows at the same time. If it helped you mark the answer as correct so it can help others too

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `input` event:

```
// ------------ \/
$('input').on('input', function(e) {
  // code...
}
```

This will fire when you enter a new value into either input.

Moreover, this will also work when you increment the input using the input increment buttons (as well as if you paste a number in). The keypress event will fire before the value is entered into your textbox (preventing you from reading the first inputted value)

See example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input').on('input', function(e) {
    $('p.length span').html(parseInt($(".length-field").val()));
    $('p.width span').html(parseInt($(".width-field").val()));

    if (parseInt($(".length-field").val()) > parseInt($(".width-field").val())) {
      $('.result').html('L > W');
    };
    
    if (parseInt($(".length-field").val()) < parseInt($(".width-field").val())) {
      $('.result').html('W > L');
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Length</p>
<input type="number" class="length-field">

<p>Width</p>
<input type="number" class="width-field">

<p class="length">length is <span></span></p>
<p class="width">width is <span></span></p>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` event and also use fallback and set value to 0 if input is empty or non numeric value present. see below code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('input').on('keyup', function(e){
      var length = parseInt($(".length-field").val()) || 0;
      var width = parseInt($(".width-field").val()) || 0;
      $('p.length span').html(length);
      $('p.width span').html(width);

     if( length > width ){
        $('.result').html('L > W');
     };

     if(length < width ){
        $('.result').html('W > L');
      };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Length
</p>
<input type="number" class="length-field">
<p>
Width
</p>    
<input type="number" class="width-field">
<p class="length">length is <span></span></p>
<p class="width">width is <span></span></p>
<p class="result">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress` because during `keypress` , the input field is still empty.

Also you can avoid using `parseInt` multiple tmes and use it only once at the begining

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    let ipLength = parseInt($(".length-field").val(), 10);
    let ipWidth = parseInt($(".width-field").val(), 10);
    $('p.length span').html(ipLength);
    $('p.width span').html(ipWidth);


    ipLength > ipWidth && $(".result").html("L > W");
    ipLength < ipWidth && $(".result").html("W > L");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Length
</p>
<input type="number" class="length-field">
<p>
  Width
</p>
<input type="number" class="width-field">
<p class="length">length is <span></span></p>
<p class="width">width is <span></span></p>
<p class="result">

</p>
```